# Question on Averages

Tags: statistics

This may be very simple to answer. But I have an excel spreadsheet. I am trying to figure out the average rate of down payments on a car. I have 70 examples. I have divided the down payment by the MSRP to get the rate. I have also taken an average of the down payments and an average of the MSRPs. The problem I am having is that when I take an average of the rates (9.06%) I am getting a different rate than when I use the average down payment and MSRP to get a rate (8.4%). My question is, does that make sense. In my mind they should be equal, but I am terrible at math so does it make sense that they are different or do I have an error in my spread sheet?

Answer (score 1):

The average of several percentages is not the overall percentage unless each percentage is a percentage of the same total. See example #3 (“Mitt Sees Red.”) [here](http://www.stevekass.com/2012/09/22/romney-below-average-and-gross/).

Q. In the four squares below, about what percentage of the area overall is red? (It’s not the average of the percentages of red in each of the four squares.)

[image]